# Get output of page and do a final "parse" with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a really long PHP/HTML page with lots of `<?php` tags all around the document. It's a really bad PHP code and I need to change some strings like XXX to ZZZ. I could try to change it in the code but it's so bad programmed and has around 7 thousand lines so I think I may try to find another alternative.

I just came out with this idea: is it possible to add a PHP code right at the bottom of the page in such a way that this PHP code "grabs" all the output code above and assign it to a variable so it can be manipulated and at the end it can be echoed?

Example:

```
<?php

balbalbla

?>

<div>BLABLA XXX</div>
....
blabla
<?php echo "blablXXXabla";>

..
```

Is it possible to add some PHP code right at the bottom of the code which grabs all of the previos "output" and change it?

Comment: Yes, search SO/Google about *PHP Output Buffering*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add code to the top and the bottom:

```
<?php
ob_start();

//code

$output = ob_get_clean();

$output = str_replace('XXX', 'ZZZ', $output);

echo $output;
```

This will start a buffer that captures all output with `ob_start()` and then after all output `ob_get_clean()` will get the contents and assign to the variable and then clear the buffer.  Now just modify the contents of `$output` and display it.

See [Output Buffering Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: thanks man! Even it there is some HTML in the middle of the buffer that is not inside <?php tag?

Comment: Yes, the entire page is processed by PHP before being output.